# most efficient way computationally to check accounts on chain?

Tags: account

I am just trying to understand the best way to check that accounts match expected values on chain.  Currently what I am doing costs 65k compute units out of a total of 200k which seems a bit extreme! At the moment I have the following at the top of a function:

```
   // we will use 3 streams, BTC,  ETH and SOL
    let btc_key =   Pubkey::from_str("HovQMDrbAgAYPCmHVSrezcSmkMtXSSUsLDFANExrZh2J").unwrap();
    let eth_key =   Pubkey::from_str("EdVCmQ9FSPcVe5YySXDPCRmc8aDQLKJ9xvYBMZPie1Vw").unwrap();
    let sol_key =   Pubkey::from_str("J83w4HKfqxwcq3BEMMkPFSppX3gqekLyLJBexebFVkix").unwrap();

    let account_info_iter = &mut accounts.iter();

    // first account is the funding account (daoplays)
    let funding_account_info = next_account_info(account_info_iter)?;


    // next accounts are the pyth oracles
    let btc_account_info = next_account_info(account_info_iter)?;
    let eth_account_info = next_account_info(account_info_iter)?;
    let sol_account_info = next_account_info(account_info_iter)?;

    // last account is the programs data account
    let program_data_account_info = next_account_info(account_info_iter)?;


    // the first account should be the funding account and should be a signer
    if !funding_account_info.is_signer {
        msg!("expected first account as signer");
        return Err(ProgramError::MissingRequiredSignature);
    }

    // only we should be able to call this function
    if funding_account_info.key != &accounts::get_expected_daoplays_key() {
        msg!("expected first account to be a daoplays account  {}", accounts::get_expected_daoplays_key());
        return Err(ProgramError::InvalidAccountData);
    }

    // check the accounts match what we expect
    if  btc_account_info.key != &btc_key || 
        eth_account_info.key != &eth_key ||
        sol_account_info.key != &sol_key 
    {
        return Err(ProgramError::InvalidAccountData);
    }

    // the next account is the programs data account
    if program_data_account_info.key != &accounts::get_expected_data_account_key() {
        msg!("expected second account to be program data account {}", accounts::get_expected_data_account_key());
        return Err(ProgramError::InvalidAccountData);
    }
```

The two helper functions are just:

```
pub fn get_expected_daoplays_key() -> Pubkey
{
    Pubkey::from_str("2BLkynLAWGwW58SLDAnhwsoiAuVtzqyfHKA3W3MJFwEF").unwrap()
}
```

and

```
pub fn get_expected_data_account_key() -> Pubkey
{
    let data_key = Pubkey::create_with_seed(
        &get_expected_daoplays_key(),
        "data_account",
        &Pubkey::from_str("CU8AequXiVdXyVKc7Vqg2jiBDJgPwapMbcBrm7EVnTtm").unwrap(),
    ).unwrap();

    return data_key;

}
```

Is the conversion from string to pubkey expensive?  Just doing the first 3 from_str calls at the top and then exiting costs 40k compute units, whereas exiting above that so the program really doesn't do anything "only" costs 13k, so it seems as though somehow that is a significant fraction.

Is there a better way to be doing this?

Many Thanks!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can see the compute unit cost of a few things in the `ComputeBudget` struct

https://github.com/solana-labs/solana/blob/d9c7bc7e780b4c6ef97d3b75263048f1b8825131/program-runtime/src/compute_budget.rs#L94-L123

Under the hood `create_with_seed` calls `hashv`

https://github.com/solana-labs/solana/blob/22d465cd57cbbc99c23e09882e57a8266fe0af1f/sdk/program/src/pubkey.rs#L203

which itself calls the syscall `sol_sha256`

https://github.com/solana-labs/solana/blob/22d465cd57cbbc99c23e09882e57a8266fe0af1f/sdk/program/src/hash.rs#L162

So according to the compute budget, it would cost `sha256_base_cost + number_of_bytes * sha256_byte_cost`

This should not consume that much, the compute unit guzzler should be something else.

You are doing `Pubkey::from_str("CU8AequXiVdXyVKc7Vqg2jiBDJgPwapMbcBrm7EVnTtm")` in your program, this can be quite expensive as the program has to decode from base58 into a `Vec<u8>`. Try to avoid in program decoding and instead trigger the decoding at compile time using something like

```
// This can also be replaced with const program_data_account = pubkey!("CU8AequXiVdXyVKc7Vqg2jiBDJgPwapMbcBrm7EVnTtm") if you are on a recent sdk
mod program_data_account {
    use super::*;
    declare_id!(CU8AequXiVdXyVKc7Vqg2jiBDJgPwapMbcBrm7EVnTtm);   
}

let data_key = Pubkey::create_with_seed(
    &get_expected_daoplays_key(),
    "data_account",
    &program_data_account::ID,
).unwrap();
```

Note: I am not sure what you are trying to achieve but if you are want to build something you can have a look at Anchor which abstract a bit of this and will allow you to use `Pubkey::find_program_address` which seem better suited here.

Comment: Awesome breakdown! I saw the from_str and immediately thought that’s got to be it. Thanks for confirming

Comment: This was a great answer, thanks! I hadn't come across either the ComputeBudget struct, or this way or defining things before compile time, super usefull!

Comment: to confirm, that just shrunk the cost of checking all these accounts to pretty much zero! thanks again

Comment: there's also a `pubkey!()` wrapper for `declare_id!()` which does the same thing, but with better self-documentation